# Why cron tasks created by WWW-DATA are not running?

Tags: 14.04, cron

I have Ubuntu 14, and want to create some cron jobs using my PHP code.

Currently, I am doing something like `crontab -u www-data`, and from my PHP code I am able to write into crontab.

If I do `crontab -u www-data -e` I can see there are some commands, but these command are not being executed, though if I add the same commands  to `crontab -e` (without specifying user), they run successfully.

Cron files also have *MANDATORY* new-line at the end.

**TL;DR:**
How can I make work cron jobs created by user `www-data` work?

**EDIT: 1**

**SOLUTION:** [click to see solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/879779/261185)

Comment: Can you share a bit more about the crontab entry ? Remember that cron usually needs the full path name of a script or command otherwise it will be ignored. You can also redirect output to a log file. And in your system log files you can search for "cron" and possibly find errors.

Comment: I just notices that www-data user is not active, because inside `/var/spool/crons/crontab` i can see `www-data` file. and that must be running as `www-data` user. so i have to give `www-data` user root rights? or what you recommend?

Comment: No! Don't use www-data for anything else than the webserver please. Use a local (user) account or even a dedicated account for just the cron jobs. Don't mess with the default apache and linux security measures ;-)

Answer (score 8):

Cron will run the www.data items.  You can verify this with this simple test:

```
$ sudo crontab -u www-data -e
```

Add this entry:

```
* * * * * date >> /tmp/date.out
```

Now examine the output with:

```
$ tail -f /tmp/date.out
```

After you have done that to ensure your crontab is working you can work the actual scripts you want to run.

the user `www-data` while not have the same path as you, so lots of commands that work from your account will not work from the `www-data` user unless you specifically set the path for that script.  www-data's default path contains only: `PATH=/usr/bin:/bin`

You can do this by exporting your path list, then placing it in a path list for the script.

You can do this with:

```
$ echo $PATH > ~/mypath.txt
```

Now append the text of the ~/mypath.txt to the top of your script as:

Your script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

export PATH=$PATH:/home/users/l/j/ljames/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
# rest of your script code here.
```

You can fine tune the path by removing some obvious items that you won't be using such as in the case of my example:

```
/home/users/l/j/ljames/bin
/usr/games
/usr/local/games
/snap/bin
```

That would leave the path line with of the script with:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin

# ... rest of your script code here
```

### PHP script run in cron

**The php test script** (`/home/users/l/j/ljames/test.php`)

```php
#!/usr/bin/php

<?php
        $string=`date`;
        print "Output from PHP script: $string";
?>
```

**The php crontab entry**

```
* * * * * php /home/users/l/j/ljames/test.php >> /tmp/date.out
```

You can examine the output with:

```
$ tail -f /tmp/date.out
Output from PHP script: Fri Feb  3 14:46:01 EST 2017

Output from PHP script: Fri Feb  3 14:47:01 EST 2017

Output from PHP script: Fri Feb  3 14:48:01 EST 2017
```

**The output verifies that crontab will run your php scripts.**  It shows that the culprit is the actual script, which would have to be debugged to function properly outside of cron first.  The likely culprit would the path list of the environment.

**Note:**
Your sytsem with your web server scripts run as user `www-data` will be more secure than if they were **run-as** you or root.  If they were as you, the script would have access to every thing that you have access to and if your web server were compromised it might even have root access with `sudo`.  Having your web server scripts **run-as** `www-data`, a compromised server will only be able to access your server.  Which, if backed up, would be easier to fix than to have to deal with your whole server.

Comment: I can see the dates being added into `/tmp/date.out`

Comment: **date** is a command it's located in a path available for `www-data`.   The same way it runs `/bin/date` it can run anything else either in it's path list or provided by a full pathname.  You can test your script just by restricting your past list to only `/usr/bin` and `/bin`.  If you can run the script, then `www-data` should be able to run it also.  You can restrict your path search to only those two paths with: `PATH=/usr/bin:/bin`.  The commands you can run will become very limited at that time.  You can recover your default path exiting the **terminal** window and starting it over.

Comment: I am not much of linux expert, but let me tell you, the command is simply `php path/to/script/script.php >> path/to/script/log.log` ... means I am just running a PHP script ... and PHP runs under `www-data` user, so shouldnt this script run?

Comment: Does the script run properly from the commandline?  Also does it run from the commanline as `www-data`?  If it has some components that are being called outside of `/usr/bin` or `/bin`, it will fail to run as `www-data` without adding that to the path of the script.  If you test it from the commandline and it fails you can run it in a bash wrapper using the path add steps I provided in the answer.

Comment: By the way, look at the **note** appended to my answer.  I understand the warnings from the user about security.  But the security is in deciding who is running the script.  When it's running under the strict access of `www-data` you'll have the most security, rather than using other accounts which might have more access to compromise your system.

Comment: @Umair Considerations for paying attention to security is valuable and appreciated when it comes to evaluating the steps.

Comment: @Umair Just a quick note that I updated the answer with a sample **PHP** script to replace the bash script example.  It works flawless.  Debugging your php script would resolve your issue.

Comment: thanks for so much time ... actually its late here and I will give it a try in morning and will accept answer.

Comment: I tried that test php script, but does work.... and I ran same command using `-u www-data` in terminal ... it works then

Comment: I found solution http://askubuntu.com/a/879779/261185

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53038/discussion-between-l-d-james-and-umair).

Answer (score 2):

That's because, traditionally (and for very good security reasons), the `www-data` user is not allowed to do anything other than web serving. No logins, no cron jobs, nada.

```
$ getent passwd www-data
www-data:x:33:33:www-data:/var/www:/usr/sbin/nologin
```

Rethink your job flow, don't try to run things as `www-data`.

Comment: Actually `www-data` can run commands.  Many web services include processes that run commands for configuring sites and other tasks.  The security is the user and the files and permissions.  www-data can't change files in your directory or anywhere that it doesn't have permission.  The user woul have to specifically give permission for those files to be changes by making them available specifically to www-data.  So by default the only files and areas available to www-data is the web pages and directories themselves or `/tmp`.

Comment: @waltinator what your commands will do? please explain? will it have no effect with apache server. never mind, I dont wanna mess up client's server :P

Comment: www-data should run dotnet as in a krestel service. Consideration of www-data is not the "user" of the apache2, instead web data services.

Answer (score 1):

I found solution. I checked cronlogs by entering

`sudo grep CRON /var/log/syslog`

And I saw message `“(CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)”`

This meant I had to mail installed.

So I ran `sudo apt-get install postfix` and now everything is working.

Comment: That was what answer was pointing out as the problem.  The solution, as provided in my answer was to run the application from the terminal and debug it.  The error would show when you run it from the terminal.  The cron works.  The resolution was to add a working application to the crontab.

Comment: that command was working fine from terminal using `-u www-data` ... the only issue was that mailer was not installed. so cron was throwing warning (script was running fine maybe, only output was not being written to that file.)

Answer (score 0):

For the user `www-data` to properly run a cron job, this file needs to exist:

`/var/spool/cron/crontabs/www-data`

with permissions:

`-rw------- 1 www-data crontab`

This should achieve that (mentioned above):

`sudo crontab -u www-data -e` ...add what you need.

If the permissions are not correct, use:

```
sudo chmod 600 /var/spool/cron/crontabs/www-data
sudo chown www-data:crontab /var/spool/cron/crontabs/www-data
```

*Editing this file directly is frowned on, even if it works, because `cron` likes to manage itself.*